# What spells can you create in Magicka using 5 different elements?

Tags: achievements, magicka

What spells can you create in Magicka using 5 different elements? The goal is to unlock the "I'm the wizard king, I can do anything!" achievement on Steam.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stone+Steam+Fire+Arcane+Shield should do the trick.

Any combination of 5 elements that don't cancel each other out will work fine.

That means, no combining Life+Arcane, Fire + Cold, or Stone+Lightning. Just about everything else is fair game.

Comment: I don't think there is a working combo without using Steam or Ice though ...

Comment: you forgot to mention lightning also nullifies water